# Office 2013 Trial Error 25004

Tags: microsoft-office, windows-8.1, microsoft-office-2013, product-key

I had some issues with getting an Office 2013 Professional Plus 2013 trial when I first installed it from TechNet, and I had to reinstall it. When I tried to activate it after reinstalling, I got the error `Error 25004.  The product key you entered cannot be used on this machine.  This is most likely due to previous Office 2010 trials being installed.`

I didn't use up my trial period, and I only had it running for about a day before uninstalling it. I've tried everything, removing registry keys (HKLM and HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office), removing files from Program Files, AppData, and ProgramData, and even got rid of some files from C:\Program Files\Common Files (Office, OfficeSoftwareProtectionService, Source Engine).

I really don't want to have to format my hard drive and reinstall Windows.

Comment: Have you tried refreshing your PC?

Comment: No, but the same issue is with refreshing as well. I would have to reinstall all of my desktop apps, and I have a lot. (Adobe Flash CS6, MS Visual Studio 2013, Notepad++, 3DS Max)

Comment: At this point, I might just refresh. It's better than nothing.

Comment: I don't know why I can't answer, but this link can be useful: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-office_install/office-2013-on-windows-81-error-25004-tried/6aec433a-6fac-4b15-988d-009d651d90dd

Answer (score 7):

I had this exact same problem. Mine was to do with the KMS activation failing after I mistakenly installed a O365 Small Business on a server and later realised I would need a VL install for terminal services RDP sessions. No matter what I did or what registry entries I deleted it didn't work. 
One person suggested (This worked for them, but would not work for me):

- Navigate to `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared`
- If there is a folder called `OFFICE15` or `OfficeSoftwareProtectionPlatform`, delete that folder.
- Navigate to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared`
- Same as above, If there is a folder called `OFFICE15` or `OfficeSoftwareProtectionPlatform`, delete that folder.
  http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-office_install/office-2013-activator-error-25004-even-after/eed3a057-4ff9-401d-af49-04c0262223af

So after hours of messing about, I figured out a work around. This will only help you if you can use a MAK key.

1. Uninstall any versions of office 2010 or 2013 you may have installed. OBVIOUSLY :)
2. [Run the office 15 Click-To-Run remove tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2739501/en-gb).
3. Reboot if required
4. Copy your Office CD to your HDD (you need to add some install instructions)
5. Launch and admin command prompt and navigate to where you copied your CD files.  Then run your office setup with the command -  `setup.exe /admin` (example `c:\2013>setup.exe /admin`)
6. This will launch the Office Customization tool.
7. Go to Licencing and user interface - select enter product key - load in your MAK key with no spaces (it will insert dashes) - accept the licence agreement
8. file - save - and name the file (eg. `2013.msp`) and save it to the updates folder within you office install. (eg `C:\2013\updates\2013.msp`)
9. exit the tool and command and run `setup.exe` as per normal. (you may need to run as admin if required)

This worked for me and I hope it solves your issues too.

Comment: Deleting the Office15 folder worked for me, when I got the same error message trying to install Sharepoint Designer 2013 alongside a copy of Office 2007. I have no idea when any portion of Office 2013 was previously installed on my machine.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

1: Open up RegEdit.

> Open up RegEdit by going to Start>Run and typing "regedit" and pressing Enter or OK. You can also enter the "regedit" command into a Command Prompt to open up the editor.

2: Locate the Office Registry Key.

> Microsoft stores all of the installation information for Office Products in   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\.`

Underneath this key you will see various version numbers, each corresponding to different versions of Office. They are as follows:

- 9.0 is Office 2000
- 10.0 is Office XP
- 11.0 is Office 2003
- 12.0 is Office 2007
- 14.0 is Office 2010

3: Locate the Corresponding Registration Key.

> Underneath each of the version number keys you should see a "Registration" key. Depending on how many Office products you have installed (Visio, Project, etc. all will be stored underneath one of those version keys) on the machine there will be multiple hashed keys present underneath the Registration key. Each of these hashed keys should have a value underneath it called "ProductName". You can use this value to correctly determine which hashed key is related to the product you want to remove.

4: Delete the Hashed Key.

> Once you have located the correct hashed registry key, delete it. As mentioned above, though, make sure you have a good backup before doing this!

5. Now try reinstalling!

Answer (score 1):

The following solved it for an installation I was working on:

1.) Navigate to C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared

If there are folders named OFFICE15 or OfficeSoftwareProtectionPlatform then delete those folders.

2.) Navigate to C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared

Same as above, if there are folders name OFFICE15 or OfficeSoftwareProtectionPlatform then delete those folders.

Now, try reinstalling.

Source: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-office_install/office-2013-activator-error-25004-even-after/eed3a057-4ff9-401d-af49-04c0262223af